# Android- What should be size of drawable left/right/top/bottom on any button/textview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I am creating drawables from  [android-asset-studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-generic.html). I have created one 32dip drawable from it. I set this image as drawable left/right, it looks good on my nexus4 as nexus4 is XHDPI and normal phone screen size. But when I run this on tablet which has MDPI density but having 10' inch screen, android picks up image from MDPI folder.

So what should be the size of drawable when creating from android-asset-studio. or do I need to manage it via drawable folders for tablets ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have not made a different layout for 10" tablet. As the tablet is of medium density it will automatically pick up images from MDPI folder you can't control it.
The one thing you can control is creating different layout for different screen sizes and Use 9 patch bitmpas they neither stretch nor shrink.

Layout selection in Android devices is as follows

```
layout -> Default (Useful for Phone layouts)
layout-large - > 5" to 7" tablets (like Galaxy Note, Kindle Fire etc)
layout-xlarge -> above 7" tablets
layout-sw<N>dp -> regardless of the screen's current orientation, your application's has at least N dps of width available for it UI.(Introduced in Android 3.2 and above).
```

More information is available [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: In meantime, I found a way to solve it. Because tablet is MDPI it is taking resources from MDPI folder. So I need to create sw-600dp for 7inch and sw-720dp for 10inch folders and put XHDPI resources(only which are required for tablet) in sw-600dp and XXHDPI in sw-720dp. It solved my problem, but I dont if it is the corret way so still waiting for more answers.

Answer (score 3):

Android uses the 3:4:6:8 scaling ratio. You can read all the fine print here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.

In short, you should use these resolutions

- 36x36 for low-density
- 48x48 for medium-density
- 72x72 for high-density
- 96x96 for extra high-density

If you are using 32 for low-density, you'll want to use

- 32x32
- 43x43 (42.6)
- 64x64
- 85x85 (85.3)

Answer (score -1):

For tablet just put the image in XHDPI and in xml assign it as a wrap_content , but you should know the size of xdpi images

Comment: You just gave several graphic designers a heart attack :D

Comment: i dont think so but you might be new

Comment: Thx for reply, but all tablets are not XHDPI there are high end samsung tablets which are MDPI. So this is not the answer.

Comment: I think you need to study the dev,android side and docmentation the purpose of xhdpi , mdpi , xxhdpi you will understand from there